# Contact Form PHP File not Working on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have created a static website on Azure, everything works fine from CSS to scrips but my contactform.php file is not loading.

I have an order contact form that needs to access this file contactform.php and I get the error
[image]

Can anyone give me some advice on how do I solve this? I have tried already using documents that are uploaded by them but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error **" The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb"** usually occurs if you are trying to use wrong http verb while accessing the file.

- A lot of content on webservices you need to use `POST` verb to consume.
- Try to clear unused or old files in the folder
- While specifying the folder name make sure you have a forward slash on the end of URL.
- Try including the CORS configuration as below,

```cs
<CorsRule>
<AllowedOrigins>*</AllowedOrigins>
<AllowedMethods>PUT,GET</AllowedMethods>
<AllowedHeaders>*</AllowedHeaders>
<ExposedHeaders>*</ExposedHeaders>
<MaxAgeInSeconds>200</MaxAgeInSeconds>
</CorsRule>
```

- If still the issue persists, add below lines in IIS webconfig,

```cs
<httpErrors>
<remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/my-page.htm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Please find below links if they are helpful.

**References:**

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841139/server-error405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed),
[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247379/unsupportedhttpverb-the-resource-doesnt-support-specified-http-verb-requesti),
[Ref3](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006Vm8lhCAB/contact-form-not-working-php-file-not-working),
[Ref4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162482/how-should-i-handle-unsupported-verbs-on-a-resource)